# Laravel laratables how to use id in enclosure

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the Laratables package. I have a function to being in the data for the datatable but I need to only query for a user by ID.

```
public function data($id) 
{

    return  Laratables::recordsOf(User::class, function($query)
    {
        return $query->where('manager_id', $id)->where('status', 'Enabled');
    });

}
```

I get an error:

> Undefined variable: id

I'm not sure how I can use the id variable inside this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `php < 7.4` then you can do something like below:

```
public function data($id) 
    {

        return  Laratables::recordsOf(User::class, function($query) use ($id)
        {

            return $query->where('manager_id', $id)->where('status', 'Enabled');
        });

    }
```

and if your are using `php 7.4` then you can use [short closure/arrow function](https://stitcher.io/blog/short-closures-in-php) for this.

```
   public function data($id) 
        {

            return  Laratables::recordsOf(User::class, fn($query) =>

             $query->where('manager_id', $id)->where('status', 'Enabled')
           );

        }
```

to read more `anonymous function` [visit this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) or [this](https://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/04/07/php-use-keyword.html)

Hope this helps.

Thanks